# creating expiry in django cause received a naive datetime

Tags: python, django, datetime, model, timezone

In my Django app,

I have in my model set for expiry this way:

```
expiry = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now()+timedelta(days=5))
```

And when i did makemigration and migrate

```
  Applying ../lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py:1451: 
 RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField AuthEmployeeSessionToken.expiry 
 received a naive datetime (2017-12-09 00:03:20.106930) while time zone support is active.
  RuntimeWarning)
../lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py:1451: 
RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField AuthEmployeeSessionToken.expiry 
received a naive datetime (2017-12-09 03:11:20.274318) while time zone support is active.
  RuntimeWarning)
 OK
```

what would be the right way to solve this problem ? I saw like timezone.now(), is that right since Im using DateTime field ? Would like a definite way of setting expiry in the model automatically when created.

Comment: Use `timezone.now()+timedelta(days=5)` in place of `datetime.now()+timedelta(days=5)`.

Comment: Or use `timezone.make_aware(date, tz)` to create a timezone aware datetime.

Comment: expiry = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now()+timedelta(days=5)). it still gives received a naive datetime